# $S = \{(x,y,z) | x^5 + y^4 + z^5 + e^z = 3\}$, why can we write $S$ as a graph $z = f(x,y)$ near (1,1,0) for smooth $f(x,y)$??

Tags: differential-geometry

So is the whole point that at $(1,1,0)$, we have our $e^z = 1$, so then around that point we have approximately

$$z = (-x^3 - y^4 +2) ^{1/5}?$$

Also we are asked to calculate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, at the point, but they are just

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 1/5(-x^3 - y^4 + 2)^{-4/5}(-4y^3),$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} =1/5(-x^3 - y^4 + 2)^{-4/5}(-3x^2)$$

which both vanish at (1,1), so I dont see how they can form a basis for the tangent plane.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g(x,y,z)=x^5+y^4+z^5+e^z-3$ then $g_z(x,y,z)=5z^4+e^z,$ which at the point $(1,1,0)$ is $5 \cdot 0^4 +e^0=1 \neq 0.$ So since the partial w.r.t. $z$ is nonzero at your point, the implicit function theorem guarantees one can get $z=f(x,y)$ near the point.

Comment: Okay thank you. So then is my $f_x(1,1) = 3x^2 = 3, f_y(1,1) = 4y^3 = 4?$ So then how do I get my basis from here?

Comment: As I recall it isn't that simple to get the partials of the implicitly defined function $f(x,y)$. One would start by replacing both copies of $z$ in the above $g(x,y,z)=0$ relation by the unknown function $f(x,y)$ and then do the partials of the result w.r.t.$x$ and w.r.t. $y$.